# Creating broken horizontal rule

Tags: html, css

I havee been looking at the source and stylesheet for the following address to work out how you can make a ... be "surrounded" by a broken horizontal rule. At the page http://www.joindiaspora.com/ there is a navigation menu having an example of it. In the html source there is used no

---

tag so I am thinking it must be done using the styling, but I can not work out how to do it. Ideas ?

Comment: Try taking a look at that page in the Firebug inspector. That would show you the CSS you're looking for and put you on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's with CSS, not an HR. There's a border-bottom on the #header DIV, and the #floating_nav is simply positioned over it. That nav contains a SPAN with a solid white background which covers the middle part of the border.

Comment: Thanks Bobby for a perfect answer and to ajm for a useful comment.